# How to authenticate through LDAP in pam?

Tags: pam, webmin

I have a application (Webmin) which has to authenticates user throught LDAP on rhel5, 6 and 7.

The package `nss_ldap` and even more its equivalent `nss-pam-ldapd` on rhel7 does not allow to get users not listed through `getent passwd`.

I used to think that for authenticating users in LDAP, we were trying to get a connection using the correct user distingish name and provided password.

Does a module pam that authenticates against LDAP exists without imposing  those users to be system user too exists?  Why should I not use such an authentication for Web applications?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such a module does exists.  It is called `pam_ldap` and is installed either with package `nss_ldap` or `nss-pam-ldap` following your Linux version.  When installing those packages you mujst configure either file `/etc/ldap.conf` or `/etc/nslcd.conf`.

Make sure service `nslcd` (RHEL7) is up and running.

For authenticating in Webmin via LDAP, your must have option `pam` selected to one pam module (let's consider webmin).  Let other option as normal.

Edit `/etc/pam.d/webmin` for replacing the followings :

```
auth required pam_ldap.so 
session required pam_ldap.so
account required pam_ldap.so
```

You may want to keep comments but consider removing others meaningful lines.

If you make this each user whom password is x in `/etc/webmin/miniserver.users` is authenticated through LDAP instead of the Webmin way.

Comment: do you mean "admin:x::::::29874509378450987234590872345" is that the `x` you're talking about in your answer?

Comment: Yes, even thought, `admin:x` is enouh.